# Has NSURLConnection got a cache?

Tags: ios, json, caching, nsurlconnection

I'm developing an iOS 4 app for iPad with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I have a problem with a JSON web service. I'm using a timer to check every 3 seconds if some data has changed. The problem is that data changes, but I can't see that changes on my app.

Data received asynchronously is always the same. It is like `NSURLConnection` has a **cache** or something like that, and it always returning the first data it takes.

Here is my code:

**ControlPanelJSON.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SBJson.h"
#import "WebServiceDelegate.h"

@interface ControlPanelJSON : NSObject
{
    SBJsonParser* parser;
    NSURLRequest* request;
    NSMutableData* receivedData;

    BOOL isEncuestaVisible;
    BOOL isInfoVisible;
    BOOL isTwitterVisible;

    id<WebServiceDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isEncuestaVisible;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isInfoVisible;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isTwitterVisible;

- (id) initWithWebServiceURLString:(NSString*)webServiceURL
                          delegate:(id<WebServiceDelegate>)del;

- (void)callWebService;

@end
```

**ControlPanelJSON.m**

```
#import "ControlPanelJSON.h"

#define kRootKey @"s"
#define kControlKey @"c"
#define kEstadoKey @"e"

#define kEncuestaTitle @"[ zzz ]"
#define kInfoTitle @"[ yyy ]"
#define kTwitterTitle @"[ xxx ]"

@implementation ControlPanelJSON

@synthesize isEncuestaVisible;
@synthesize isInfoVisible;
@synthesize isTwitterVisible;

- (id) initWithWebServiceURLString:(NSString*)webServiceURL
                          delegate:(id<WebServiceDelegate>)del
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        delegate = [del retain];
        request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: webServiceURL]
                                        cachePolicy: NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed
                                    timeoutInterval: 60.0];
        parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [parser release];
    [request release];
    [receivedData release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)callWebService
{
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (theConnection)
    {
        // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
        // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        [delegate errorReceivedWithMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"CONNERROR", nil)];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDelegate

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // This method is called when the server has determined that it
    // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse.

    // It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
    // redirect, so each time we reset the data.

    // Cuando se recibe este mensaje se debe descartar todo lo recibido anteriormente.
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    [receivedData release];

    // inform the user
    [delegate errorReceivedWithMessage:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error - %@ %@",
      [error localizedDescription],
      [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]]];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{   
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* datos = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil]; // TODO: Otro error que manejar

    [connection release];
    //[receivedData release];
    //[parser release];
    [json_string release];

    NSArray* data = [datos objectForKey:kRootKey];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary* object = [data objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString* controlName = [object objectForKey:kControlKey];
        NSString* controlEstado = [object objectForKey:kEstadoKey];

        if ([controlName isEqualToString: kEncuestaTitle])
        {
            isEncuestaVisible = ([controlEstado isEqualToString: @"1"]);
            continue;
        }
        else if ([controlName isEqualToString: kInfoTitle])
        {
            isInfoVisible = ([controlEstado isEqualToString: @"1"]);
            continue;
        }
        else if ([controlName isEqualToString: kTwitterTitle])
        {
            isTwitterVisible = ([controlEstado isEqualToString: @"1"]);
            continue;
        }
    }

    [delegate dataReceived];
}

@end
```

After this code line:

```
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I added a NSLog, and I always getting the same `json_string`

{"ctrls": [ { "control": "[ xxx ]","estado": "0" },{ "control": "[ yyy ]","estado": "0" },{ "control": "[ zzz ]","estado": "0" } ] }

Any clue?

Comment: You can change the cache policy and fool around with other things, but you can still get bit by caching in the network.  The only reasonably foolproof solution is to add a bogus parameter to your URL which you increment with each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the cache policy when you create your `NSURLRequest` to:

```
NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use:

```
NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
```

Please note that `NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed` is `NSCachedURLResponse` class, not `NSURLRequest`.

According to `NSURLRequest.h` header file, `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` is unimplemented as shown below.

```
enum
{
    NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0,

    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData = 1,
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData = 4, // Unimplemented
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,

    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2,
    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad = 3,

    NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData = 5, // Unimplemented
};
typedef NSUInteger NSURLRequestCachePolicy;
```